# SQL- Insert into table only if the primary key value isn't already in the table

Tags: c#, sql-server

If I have a table:

```
 Table A
 Column1(Primary Key) | Column2 | Column3
```

How can I assure that when I insert a new row, that it will not insert the new row if a row with that primary key already exist?

My current c# code and SQL command:

```
string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blah"].ConnectionString;

string cmdString = "INSERT INTO TableA (Column1,Column2,Column3) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = cmdString;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", x);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", y);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // don't hide it
        }
    }
}
```

Is this handled automatically since Column1 is specified as primary?

Edit:

I am getting an error with the SQL command below with the WHERE, any ideas?

> "INSERT INTO TableA (Column1,Column2) VALUES (@val1, @val2) WHERE
>   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE Column1 = @val1)"

Comment: add `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE Column1 = @val1)`

Comment: Why cant we make that auto generated

Comment: is there not a UNIQUE/DISTINCT tag I can use or anything? I have to use WHERE NOT EXISTS on a whole new query?

Comment: SQL Server will prevent you from inserting duplicate values in PK by producing an error. If you don't want an error, you have to add the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: What is the better solution than AddWithValue()?

Comment: The article proposed a better solution.

Comment: Do you investigate a solution that use MERGE instruction instead INSERT ?

Comment: Have not, thanks for the suggestion. Will look into

Comment: I tried adding WHERE NOT EXISTS in my SQL command and got a error back with that syntax, did I make a mistake?, check OP for edit

Comment: `INSERT INTO TableA (Column1,Column2) 
SELECT @val1, @val2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE Column1 = @val1)`

Comment: Did not work - error 'Incorrect syntax near '@val1'.'

Answer (score 0):

As @tdelepine suggested. You can use the merge method in your command. Here is a quick example. For you use, you would just need to get rid of the "When Matched Then" clause. I use this method in Stored Procedures a lot to do an Add or Update.

```
MERGE [dbo].[TableName] AS tar
USING (SELECT @Key As UserKey) AS src
ON (tar.[KeyColumn] = src.UserKey)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [ValueColumn] = @Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([KeyColumn], [ValueColumn])
    VALUES (@Key, @Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check beforehand. If the primary key exists, the second insert will fail. Just trap that error condition so you can take whatever action makes sense when a duplicate is attempted.

This is wise both because (a) it avoids race conditions, and (b) It's Easier To Ask For Forgiveness Than Permission is generally a good programming philosophy (usually leads to cleaner code).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you're using a stored procedure but not necessary.

If the primary key already exists but the other values are updated, do you want to update the other columns?

```
MERGE TableA with (holdlock) AS target
    USING (SELECT @val1, @val2, @val3) AS source (value1, value2, value2)
    ON (target.Column1 = source.value1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET
            Column2 = source.value2,
            Column3 = source.value3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Column1, Column2, Column3)
    VALUES (source.value1, source.value2, source.value3);
```

You can do this without merge. This is more useful when your input is a table value parameter or a SELECT from another table. It allows you to perform a number of these in a single operation. You can also use an OUTPUT INTO clause with your insert to return the primary keys that were actually new and inserted.